# Saving SketchUp information to database

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I'm trying to create a plugin with the SketchUp Ruby API that will monitor a SketchUp model for changes and export information about each entity (height, width, area, volume, material, ect). I have this working by looping through all entities in the model and reporting their characteristics but as the file grows larger this export loop takes way too long to be viable.

Is there anyway to link SketchUp with a database so updating a entity updates only that one in the database, avoiding the loop through the entire model? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm reluctant to comment because I'm not familiar with the API, but if the API doesn't have what you need built-in, would it be feasible (though klunky and maybe problematic) to create wrappers for selected API methods that would hold lists of entities affected by the method, so you could compare pre- vs post- values? Aside: I'm interested in familiarizing myself with the the API. I'd prefer a book on the subject, but haven't found any. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe, with 42985 edges, 19715 faces and 3763 groups I'm worried about the speed of storing that many entities. I haven't read any books on the SketchUp API and they do update it for different versions so you have to be careful you don't read outdated info. The [docs](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/) aren't that bad though and their [forums](http://forums.sketchup.com/c/developers) are very active and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a record per entity in the database. When time comes to update an entity, you'll have (assuming you have a key for the entity) only to update that one record. That should be quicker than rewriting an entire file.

Comment: That is pretty much what I was thinking but I'm not sure how to watch for entity updates. The API offers EntityObserver but that doesn't watch for dimension or material changes. The API docs for Observers are very vague.

Comment: You can give me a link to the API?

Comment: It seems like the API has pretty much everything you need. You seem to be close to a solution. Adding an EntityObserver seems like a good approach. If the onChangeEntity is called for an Face, you should be able to get the new dimension as in: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/entity.  Look for the call to : if entity.is_a? SketchUp::Face...  Saving the whole thing and reconstructing it seems like a lot of work but doable if there's nothing missing in the API.